# SQL Server JSON_VALUE syntax

Tags: json, sql-server

I created a SQL Server Table with 25 columns.  One of my columns is actually JSON text, stored as nvarchar(max).

Now I need to able to query this JSON column and parse out the various attributes.  I have tried applying JSON_VALUE to my column but am doing something wrong; my query runs but returns NULL for all the values.

The JSON itself looks like:

```
[
 {
  "lineName":"GHjr",
  "pipeDiameter":"12",
  "pipeLength":"52000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"107"
 },
 {
  "lineName":"Ks3R",
  "pipeDiameter":"9",
  "pipeLength":"40000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"80"
 }
]
```

The SQL I am using is:

```
select
 DOC_ID, LINE_SPECS,
 JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName')     as line_name,
 JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.pipe_Diameter') as diameter
from dbo.MY_TEST_DOCS
where ISJSON(LINE_SPECS) > 0
  and len(LINE_SPECS) > 3
```

However, my 2 "parsed" columns are returning all NULL.  How do I parse the five attributes from this column?

Comment: Put the `JSON_VALUE` in `strict` mode to see if any errors come up. The default mode is `lax` and won't produce errors, it will just return `NULL`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server  Also, `$.pipe_Diameter` I think should be `$.pipeDiameter`

Comment: If you remove the square brackets and make your select match the case-sensitive name in the JSON, it will return a value

Comment: Actually the brackets might be ok if its an array.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work. You can use JSON_QUERY instead, but still need a name before the square brackets to call.

Comment: Wasn't sure if we were seeing the whole JSON or not.

Comment: The JSON "snippet" I pasted in indeed all the JSON for a particular record. And, yes, it is indeed an array.
Yes, I see I have a typo...

@dfundako - are you saying I need to remove the opening & closing brackets from within the JSON column itself?  So, I would need to run an Update to clean-up the text *BEFORE* trying to query it, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Without the [] ISJSON is returning false
With [] ISJSON retuns true
Without the [] JSON_VALUE returns NULLs
With [] JSON_VALUE returns values
```

dbfddle.uk has sql server 2016 available....

> ```
> create table test (LINE_SPECS nvarchar(max));
>
> insert into test values (N'
>  {
>   "lineName":"GHjr",
>   "pipeDiameter":"12",
>   "pipeLength":"52000",
>   "pressure":"15",
>   "volume":"107"
>  },
>  {
>   "lineName":"Ks3R",
>   "pipeDiameter":"9",
>   "pipeLength":"40000",
>   "pressure":"15",
>   "volume":"80"
>  }
> ');
>
> select * 
> from test
> where ISJSON(LINE_SPECS) > 0
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | LINE_SPECS |
> | :--------- |
> ```

> ```
> select
>       JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName')     as line_name
>     , JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.pipeDiameter') as diameter
> from test
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> line_name | diameter
> :-------- | :-------
> GHjr      | 12
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4cfd30acfb6ae32bd398d0e9fa48136d)*

Comment: (and others), your answer(s) really helped!!  The JSON I was struggling with included the opening and closing brackets.  I created a 2nd column, WITHOUT those brackets, and JSON_VALUE worked as expected.
Thank you all for your assistance!

Comment: @CarCrazyBen could you please "accept" this answer?  Stackoverflows with questions that appear unanswered and this makes it harder for other people to locate answers to their similar problems.